# How to Periodically Update Parent (Screen) Class UI from Child (BoxLayout) Class (Python with Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

Goal:

Periodic update of parent (screen) class / UI from child (boxlayout) class. The`conf2.dat` is occasionally updated (from various other screens), and I want the UI to update every 5 seconds or so by re-running this class.

Latest code update:

1. In the `__init__` function, I have  `Clock.schedule_interval(self.create_button, 1)`, which should cause the `create_button` function to rerun every second.
2. At the top of the `create_button` function, I have `self.box_share.clear_widgets()`, which should clear all the widgets so they can be repopulated (per the instructions outlined further down the `create_button` function).

Action:

1. I run the code
2. I navigate to `NoTags` screen by clicking the button with text title 'updating sequence'
3. I make changes to buttons that were dynamically created under scrollview by clicking on them. They successfully change color. This information is written to the `conf2.dat` file.
4. I navigate to `SequenceScreen` screen by first clicking 'home' button, then clicking 'sequence display' button. This `SequenceScreen` screen is the screen I wish to have updated to reflect the changes made to conf2.dat file.

Result:

UI associated with`SequenceScreen(Screen)` class still does not update per changes made from UI associated with `NoTags(Screen)` class.

However, when I restart the app altogether, I find the `SequenceScreen` UI successfully updated.

Suspicion:

I'm just one line of code away from getting this UI to update properly.

**Python Code:**

```
from kivy.app import App
# kivy.require("1.10.0")
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
#from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.storage.dictstore import DictStore
import pickle
import datetime, threading
import time
from kivy.clock import mainthread

class BackHomeWidget(Widget):
    pass

class SequenceBoxLayout_NoEdits(BoxLayout):
    box_share = ObjectProperty()
    config_file = DictStore('conf2.dat')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SequenceBoxLayout_NoEdits, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"       
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.create_button, 1)

    def create_button(self, *args):      
        self.box_share.clear_widgets()

        top_button_share = 1.1
        color = (.4, .4, .4, 1)
        for i in range(25):
            top_button_share -= .4
            id_ = "part" + str(i + 1)

            if self.config_file.exists(id_):
                btn_color = self.config_file[id_]["background_color"]
            else:
                self.config_file.put(id_, background_color=color)
                btn_color = color

            button_share = Button(background_normal='',
                                  background_color=btn_color,
                                  id=id_,
                                  pos_hint={"x": 0, "top": top_button_share},
                                  size_hint_y=None,
                                  height=60,
                                  font_size = 30,
                                  text= str(i+1)
            self.box_share.add_widget(button_share)

        #Clock.schedule_interval(self.parent.ids.updatedisplay.create_button(self, *args) , 1)
        #self.parent.ids.updatedisplay.create_button(self, *args)

class SequenceBoxLayout_NoTag(BoxLayout):
    box_share = ObjectProperty()
    config_file = DictStore('conf2.dat')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SequenceBoxLayout_NoTag, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_button)

    def create_button(self, *args):
        df = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx","Sheet1")
        parts = df['parts'].values.tolist()

        top_button_share = 1.1
        color = (.4, .4, .4, 1)
        for i in range(len(parts)):
            top_button_share -= .4
            id_ = "part" + str(i + 1)

            if self.config_file.exists(id_):
                btn_color = self.config_file[id_]["background_color"]
            else:
                self.config_file.put(id_, background_color=color)
                btn_color = color

            button_share = Button(background_normal='',
                                  background_color=btn_color,
                                  id=id_,
                                  pos_hint={"x": 0, "top": top_button_share},
                                  size_hint_y=None,
                                  height=60,
                                  font_size = 30,
                                  text= str(i+1)+ ".   " + str(parts[i]))
            if self.parent.name == 'notags':
                button_share.bind(on_press=self.update_buttons_notag)
            self.box_share.add_widget(button_share)

    def update_buttons_notag(self, button):
        button.background_color = 0.86,0.54,0.04,1
        self.config_file.put(button.id, background_color=(0.86,0.54,0.04,1))

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SequenceScreen(Screen):
    pass

class NoTags(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("updatelistexample.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

KV Code:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:
    NoTags:
    SequenceScreen:

<SmallNavButton@Button>:    
    font_size: 32
    size: 125, 50    
    color: 0,1,0,1

<BigButton@Button>:
    font_size: 40
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.15
    color: 0,1,0,1 

<BackHomeWidget>:
    SmallNavButton:
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        text: "Home"
        pos: root.x, root.top - self.height

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        BigButton:
            on_release: app.root.current = "notags"
            text: "updating sequence"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "top": 0.4} 
        BigButton:
            on_release: app.root.current = "sequence"
            text: "sequence display"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "top": 0.7}

<AnotherScreen>:
    name: "newgarage"

<NoTags>:
    name: "notags"
    SequenceBoxLayout_NoTag:
    BackHomeWidget:
    FloatLayout:
        BigButton:
            text: "Select Parts w/o Tags"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top": 0.6}
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (0.4,0.4,0.4,1)           

<SequenceBoxLayout_NoEdits>:
    box_share: box_share
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: box_share
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            spacing: 5
            padding: 130
            height: self.minimum_height
            canvas:
                Color: 
                    rgb: 0, 0, 0
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

<SequenceBoxLayout_NoTag>:
    box_share: box_share
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: box_share
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            spacing: 5
            padding: 130
            height: self.minimum_height
            canvas:
                Color: 
                    rgb: 0, 0, 0
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size         

<SequenceScreen>:
    name: "sequence"
    SequenceBoxLayout_NoEdits:
        id: updatedisplay
    BackHomeWidget:
```

Comment: if you want us to help you, you should strive and create a [mcve]

Comment: I just updated the question. It now contains a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: Ok, it makes more sense now, so your issue is that you have two DictStore, pointing to the same file, and trying to use that to communicate between the two classes, at run time? I think you rather want to use the same instance (for example shared on `MainApp` since it's easy to refet to it from anywhere (`app` in kv and `App.get_running_app()` in python).

Comment: Ok, I made an attempt to apply your suggestion. I defined `config_file` in the build function of `MainApp`. I then declared `app = App.get_running_app()` in each function that makes use of `config_file`. I then replaced all other `config_file` references with `app.config_file`. The error I get now is **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config_file'**.

Comment: Ah, I got it to work now! I was getting the above-mentioned error because `self.config_file` in my code should be changed to `app.config_file` (as opposed to `self.app.config_file`. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Credit:**

Based on advice provided by @Tshirtman in the comments thread of the posted question...

**Summary:**

The problem with the code had to do with the fact that I had two different DictStore pointing to the same file, which was tripping up the communication between both classes.

The solution was to instead use only one DictStore and define that variable in the App class, then reference that particular variable in the child classes [using `App.get_running_app()`], like so:

**Define config_file in App class:**

```
class MainApp(App):
    config_file = DictStore('conf2.dat')

    def build(self):
        return presentation
```

**Reference App variable in child classes:**

```
class SequenceBoxLayout_NoEdits(BoxLayout):
    ...
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SequenceBoxLayout_NoEdits, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"       
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.create_button, 1)

    def create_button(self, *args):      
        self.box_share.clear_widgets() 
        app = App.get_running_app() 
        ...
        for i in range(len(parts)):
            ...
            if app.config_file.exists(id_):
                btn_color = app.config_file[id_]["background_color"]
            else:
                app.config_file.put(id_, background_color=color)
                ...
            ...

class SequenceBoxLayout_NoTag(BoxLayout):
    ...
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SequenceBoxLayout_NoTag, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_button)

    def create_button(self, *args):
        ...
        app = App.get_running_app() 
        ...
        for i in range(len(parts)):
            ...

            if app.config_file.exists(id_):
                btn_color = app.config_file[id_]["background_color"]
            else:
                app.config_file.put(id_, background_color=color)
                ...
            ...

    def update_buttons_notag(self, button):       
        app = App.get_running_app()         
        ...
        app.config_file.put(button.id, background_color=(0.86,0.54,0.04,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Clock` has a `schedule_interval` method, which works much like the `schedule_once` one, but will be called *every* `n` seconds instead of just once after `n` seconds.

So you could certainly just change that call in `__init__` and start the `create_button` by calling `self.box_share.clear_widgets()` to remove widgets from the previous call before re-creating them.

This might be a bit wasteful, if you find yourself recreating a lot of widgets even if nothing changed, so you could add some logic to first check if the data didn't change, or even if it did, just reuse the old buttons if possible.

```
box = self.box_share
old_buttons = box.children[:]
box.clear_widgets()

# [your logic about computing the list of parts]

for i, p in enumerate(parts): # this is much better than doing range(len(parts))
    # [the logic to get the content of the button]
    if old_buttons: # check there are still buttons in the list of old buttons
        btn = old_buttons.pop()
    else:
        btn = Button(
            background_normal='',
            background_color=btn_color,
            pos_hint={"x": 0, "top": top_button_share},
            # etc, all the things that are common to all your buttons
            # but really, hardcoding them like this is a bit painful,
            # you should use a subclass of button so you can style it
            # in a kv rule so it would apply to all of them directly
        )

     btn.id=id_
     btn.text = "{}.    {}".format(i+1, p)
     btn.pos_hint["top"] = top_button_share
     # re-apply any other property that might have changed for this part
     box.add_widget(btn)
```

But this logic is quite a common one, actually, and there are other things you can do to improve things in even more situations, though that's quite some work.

Thankfully, you are not the first one to need such thing, and we have been blessed with the wonderful `RecycleView`, which automates all of this and more, you just need to feed it a `data` directory, and it'll create the necessary widgets to fill the visible part of the scrollview if there is enough widgets to warrant scrolling, and automatically update when data changes, and when you scroll to see different parts of the list. I encourage you to check it, yourself. but the end result would certainly be something like.

```
<PartButton@Button>:
    id_: None
    part: ''
    text: '{}.    {}'.format(self.id, self.part)

<SequencedBoxLayout@Recycleview>:
    parts: self.get_parts()

    viewclass: 'PartButton'
    data:
        [
        {
        id_: i,
        part: part
        } for i, p in enumerate(self.parts or [])
        ]
    RecycleBoxLayout:
```

Comment: I'm still having difficulty updating the UI. I updated my question with runnable code, incorporating your answer as best as I could understand (minus the efficiency suggestions, which I will definitely take a closer look at once I get this UI auto-updating). Did I misunderstand your answer? (Sorry, I'm new to this)